# Using IF whiting a FOR in Batch

Tags: recursion, batch-file

I need a script that checks the name of a CDG file and if is not present in the same folder another file with the *same* name in .mp3, then deletes the cdg file.

I thought to implement it with this simple code:

```
@echo off
for /R %1 %%f in (*.cdg) do (
   if exist %%~nf.mp3 (
      del %%f
     )
)
```

But it return me with a *syntax error* in IF construct.

I tried to google it but it seems no-one had same problem (or i'm really bad in using google)

Can please someone tell me where i'm wrong?

Comment: What is the value of %1? How do you know the error is in your IF statement? What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, heres an easy way of doing this with `forfiles` if your using Windows 7:

```
forfiles /m "*.cfg" /c "cmd /c if exist @fname.mp3 del @path"
```

That alone should work fine, and it's short enough to be typed directly in cmd.

Mona

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the name of the file containing spaces. If so then:

```
@echo off
for /R %1 %%f in (*.cdg) do (
if exist "%%~nf.mp3" (
   del %%f
   )
)
```

**NB : Quotation Marks**

Also, You should look into `forfiles` (since you'll only be needing one line of code) but that will only work if your using Windows 7.

Mona

Comment: Reasonable guess, but FOR variables in IF statements do not need to be quoted, even if they contain spaces or poison characters. The same is true for delayed expansion. But regular expansion does require the quotes.

Comment: `for %%f in (*.txt) do if exist %%~nf%%~xf copy %%f 123.txt` <--- @dbenham Dave, in this example it does need quoting of the `%%f` if the name has spaces, but it's true that the if exist portion doesn't need quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl:

```
@echo off
for /R "%~1" %%f in (*.cdg) do (
   if exist "%%~dpnf.mp3" (
      del "%%f"
     )
)
```

Comment: You forgot the `f` in `%%~dp`. But even simpler is `if exist "%%~dpnf.mp3"`

Comment: @dbenham Ta.  Have modified it.